# npm is not compatible with Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I had node installed in my machine and everything was working fine. During an online course made in 2019, the instructor was using an earlier version of npm **(v5.5.1)** and advised everyone to use the same version with him for follow up reasons. So I downgraded to **v5.5.1** but now I keep getting one same error (incompatibility) for almost all commands. I read some solutions to similar problems here and even tried extra steps but the problem still persists.
I uninstalled node from my system, restarted the system and reinstalled node but the version of npm still remained **v5.5.1**.
I tried to uninstall npm from the command line `npm uninstall -g npm` but it threw incompatibility error.
I searched the web for compatible version of node.js for npm **v5.5.1** and got node **v10.15.1** which I downloaded installed with several system restarts but my node and npm still remain incompatible. Please what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) which is the **Node Version Manager**, cURL:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

commands:

```
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version>
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
nvm ls                      List versions (installed versions are blue)
```

Helpful reads:

- [How can the default node version be set using NVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm)
- [How to change node version with nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785383/how-to-change-node-version-with-nvm)

Comment: I had to download nvm executable file for windows and followed the rest of your steps and now everything works well again. Thank you very much, bless you!