# Mac: Expo being updated but not working and resolving out-of-date packages

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I have the expo-cli working fine on Windows with a project initialized and running which I'd like to be able to do on this machine. However, on Mac, it keeps saying that the package is getting updated but when I try running `expo init` or the expo command globally it doesn't work:

```
/Users/daggerpov/.npm/bin/expo -> /Users/daggerpov/.npm/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/Users/daggerpov/.npm/bin/expo-cli -> /Users/daggerpov/.npm/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
+ expo-cli@4.11.0
updated 2 packages in 94.007s
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % expo
zsh: command not found: expo
```

Also, I get a bunch of deprecation warnings but I've heard it's expected by installing this through npm, nevertheless here's the full output:

```
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
/Users/daggerpov/.npm/bin/expo -> /Users/daggerpov/.npm/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/Users/daggerpov/.npm/bin/expo-cli -> /Users/daggerpov/.npm/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
+ expo-cli@4.11.0
updated 2 packages in 94.007s
```

What I've done to try resolving the issue of not being able to use the `expo` command has been:

- installing Watchman through homebrew (it had no errors and came out fine)
- running `cd ~/node_modules && npm i expo-cli && sudo npm i -g expo && sudo npm i --global expo-cli`
- I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvuZn6gX_Q4) YouTube tutorial which said to run `npm install expo-cli global` which resulted in this:

```
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % npm install expo-cli global
(just some of the same deprecation warnings)
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/daggerpov/node_modules/expo-cli
npm WARN daggerpov@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN daggerpov@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /Users/daggerpov/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/Users/daggerpov/node_modules/expo-cli'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/daggerpov/.npm/_logs/2021-09-10T06_57_31_944Z-debug.log
```

Perhaps since my node version is a little more recent than the LTS it could pose a problem?

```
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % node --version
v14.8.0
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % npm --version
6.14.8
```

UPDATE: I've changed my node version to the LTS and have made sure that usr/local/bin is in $PATH but this did not fix the issue.

```
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/daggerpov/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
daggerpov@Daniels-MBP ~ % node --version
v14.17.6
```

Comment: Try some older node versions with n -> https://github.com/tj/n or nvm.

Comment: I've installed nvm by following what was outlined in this issue: https://gist.github.com/mike-casas/6d489bebf48d89f5109cd1395aabe150
then I ran `nvm install node` and it gave me v16.9.0. I will update the question or post an answer if this leads me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed nvm by following what was outlined in [this issue](http://gist.github.com/mike-casas/6d489bebf48d89f5109cd1395aabe150): then I ran `nvm install node` and it gave me v16.9.0. Then, I ran `npm install --global expo-cli` as I did before and the expo command now runs fine.

Important note:
The expo command would only work right after using the `nvm install node` command so when I went to VSC I had to use that before every session. I will try to find a solution to this issue and edit this answer accordingly. So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785482/13368695) is how you configure your node version using nvm and have it stay. Personally, I did `nvm use 16.9.0` then when I checked my node version it saved.

Comment: it's solved. why are you commenting this? @MichaelBahl