# CRA: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Even though I have latest node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When I run

```
node -v
v14.17.6
```

Then I tried

```
 sudo npx create-react-app custom-hooks
```

I got

> error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.15.2: The engine "node" is
> incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10.12.0 ||
> `>=`12.0.0". Got "11.10.0" error Found incompatible module info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this
> command.

Can someone help? How I come get this error when terminal told me I have 14.17.6 as I showed.
**How come it says Got "11.10.0"?**

Comment: are you see this as a warning in your console while installing packages?
or do you get these errors which prevents you from installing CRA?

Comment: @novonimo No this prevents installation

Comment: are you tried CRA installation without "sudo" ?

Comment: You can try `nvm` and change your node version. You can install multiple node versions using the `nvm`.

Comment: @Asifvora I changed the version to latest using nvm already (14.17.6) as shown. In the error message in my question it says `Got 11.10.0` where does it take it from?

Comment: try `nvm use node version` example : `nvm use 14.17.6`

Comment: @novonimo It worked without sudo.  But it had large delay initially (that was confusing me probably)

Comment: @Asifvora I did that already running without sudo worked

Comment: For more `nvm` explore here how to set up and all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785383/how-to-change-node-version-with-nvm/53785482

Comment: Try `which node` vs `sudo which node`, and `sudo node -v` You likely have a separate Node 11 which running as sudo prefers.

Answer (score 2):

you are using two different **environments** or **privilege** and this is why you get this error.

you are trying to get your node version with:

```
node -v
```

you could get it via

```
sudo node -v
```

usually, beginners will be caught in this type of problem and it's okay.

**Summary**:
your node version in the actual environment and `superuser` environment is different and you are trying to scramble them together.

**General Advice:** don't use `sudo` before your Linux commands at all and just use it as needed (and you know about it).