# How to change Node version for specific project using NVM?

Tags: node.js, package, package.json, nvm, yarn-v2

When I run `yarn install` in my React Native project I get the error `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12". Got "14.15.4"`.

Where the `12` comes from is that in the package.json the line is

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12"
},
```

Where the `14.5.4` comes from is that when I run `node --version` it returns `14.5.4`. I'm using NVM. Is there a way to change the `14.5.4` to `12` so that I can run `yarn install` without error?

Comment: Yes, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785383/how-to-change-node-js-version-with-nvm for a how to do.