When I try to host firebase function then giving below error of node version. Expected version should be 18 and I'm using v20
npm warn EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm warn EBADENGINE   package: 'backend@1.0.0',
npm warn EBADENGINE   required: { node: '18' },
npm warn EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.11.0', npm: '10.8.1' }
npm warn EBADENGINE }
npm error code 1
npm error path D:\Projects\Website\server\node_modules\farmhash
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm error prebuild-install warn install Request timed out
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@20.11.0 | win32 | x64


My projects are built on version 20 of Node and when I downgrade the version then it will impact the dependencies in my other projects.
Any recommended solutions?

Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal reproducible example of a project that doesn't work the way you expect.  Be sure to include your package.json and the specific set of steps you take that causes the error.  The error message alone is not necessarily helpful - we need to see what caused it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I had a similar problem in that I had to run an earlier version of Node to use Jest.
Try this answer for using different versions of Node. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785482/25009153.
.
